# How to get change in HTML DOM in LabVIEW?

Tags: html, labview

I am doing IOT related project in Labview using Arudino as hardware.
I was able switch off/on an led on Arudino by Pressing OFF/ON on website by using datasocket vi. Now what i want is to control the intensity of led from Website.

I have a range slider in my website and its real time value can be viewed in textarea,div,input type.

Is there any way i can get that real time value that is being changed in HTML DOM in Labview.
I know that datasocket vi returns the html source code but not the HTML DOM.

I dont want to use the Web Publishing Services as they dont work in my Laptop.
This is the link im referring for datasocket.
[Datasocket Labview](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/3224/en/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like creating a web socket, but I expect the easiest thing is to use a web service. You can create one in LV and add a setLEDIntensity method to it and call it from your JS code. You can find a simple example [here](https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-41659) and in other documents in that community.

Comment: i was trying that example myself but i got stuck when i was not able to publish the web service. It alwasys gave me an error. Isn't there any way by using Internet Toolkit?

Comment: The Internet toolkit is old. Maybe it has tools which could do this (CGI?), but I wouldn't even bother finding out, because they're no longer relevant. As mentioned, a socket or a service is probably your best bet. If the service doesn't work, either figure out what the problem is (e.g. try one of the shipping examples) or switch to sockets.

Answer (score 1):

Use WebSocket API for LabVIEW to send and receive data from the web. This is the best option for you.

https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-40572